# Angular 2 application buttons are not responding in iOS 9.x

Tags: angular, button, click, ios9

My application runs on Angular 2 and has a lot of HTML elements with (click) attributes bound to it for performing the click action. Unfortunately, some of those buttons are not responding, in iOS 9.x browsers. Desktop browsers & iOS 10.x does behave properly.
At times in 9.x, one out of twenty clicks would work.
Anybody having any thoughts on this ?